# Jspm + Angular 2 empty file name Error

Tags: angular, systemjs, jspm

We're having a problem on one of the computers while trying to load the project.

this is our package.json:

```
{
 ...
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "angular2": "npm:angular2@^2.0.0-beta.8",
      "d3": "npm:d3@^3.5.16",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@^0.1.3",
      "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@^0.6.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {}
  },
 ...
}
```

the config.js is:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: false,
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  map: {
  }
});
```

i deleted the map for the question, it creates it again when you do jspm i.

The index.html is:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="temp/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>   
    <base href="/">

    <script>
             System.import('reflect-metadata').then(function(){
            System.import('boot.js');    
    });   
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

**without the reflect meta-data angular 2 fails to load (anybody got an idea how to fix that?).**

after running the dependencies installation (npm i , jspm i). 
We try to access localhost:8000, and the jspm fails to load the angular 2 project with the following problem:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with status of 404 (Not found) http://locallhost:8000/.js
```

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLd33.png)

**it seems there's something wrong with the dependency loading inside the systemjs, we obviously don't have a reference to an empty file, and it's not code related because the same code works on other machines.
anybody got an idea?**

Comment: Didn't see it was not working for just one pc... Also I never made it working with angular-polyfills. So I would suggest to remove it (reflect-metadata also) and add to your boot.js or  app.js the libraries: `import 'es6-shim'; import 'zone.js/dist/zone.min.js'; import 'reflect-metadata';`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a transpiler defined, you have to setup babel or typescript,... etc.

`jspm dl-loader babel` or you can use `jspm init` to amend it.

see also the documentation:
https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: that is sadly not correct, we already transpile by our-self using a gulp task.

Comment: I understand, but I think it is still searching for a file. so you cannot put false there...

Comment: i'll get back to you after trying this, but if that's the case it should never work, while it does work on some of our machines.